# Reading data from JSON reply with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been having trouble accessing this piece of content in a json object. Here is my code for fetching data:

```
function getEntries(key){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + key + "&jscmd=details&callback=mycallback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

The reply I get looks like this: 
[image]

How do I access the pointed object if the key is different for every search?

Comment: data.ISBN not working ?

Comment: No, but I found out that data.["ISBN:" + key ] does...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
data["ISBN:"+key]
```

Where key is the key you are passing to the function

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it after all...

```
function getEntries(key){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + key + "&jscmd=details&callback=mycallback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data["ISBN:"+key]);
            }
        });
    }
```

did the trick.

Comment: So maybe use the extra 3 minutes to think it over before posting the question? ;-)

Comment: You wouldn't believe me if I told you that I've been banging my head over this for the last 20 minutes. The answer flashed right after I clicked post.